# Angular unit test error ( finalSprintsList.map is not a function ) with jasmine karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular6, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write unit test for my component method i.e **populateSprintDropDown**. Here is my component code

```
setResponseForButton() {
 let sortedList = this.teamboardService.sortSprintsBasedOnEndDate();
 this.populateSprintDropDown(sortedList);
}

//finalSprintList that is returned by service is = [{id: "3712", name: "DCT 3.128.1 Sp1 (11Dec-24Dec)", 
status: "ACTIVE", sprintLink: null, startDate: "2019-12-11"}]


populateSprintDropDown(finalSprintList: Array<any>) {
  this.sprintsList = (<Array<Sprint>>finalSprintList).map(sprint => ({ item_id: sprint.id, item_text: sprint.name }));
}
```

Test:

```
  it('populate sprint in sprint dropdown upon button click', () => {
    let list = [{item_id: "3712", item_text: "DCT 3.128.1 Sp1 (11Dec-24Dec)"}]
    component.sprintsList  = list;
    const spy = spyOn(component, 'populateSprintDropDown').and.callThrough();
    component.setResponseForButton(); 
    expect(spy).toBeDefined();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

But when I run my test I get this error:

TypeError: finalSprintsList.map is not a function. 
I cannot understand what does it mean and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock the method `teamboardService.sortSprintsBasedOnEndDate`.

Please note that no spy is needed for method `component.populateSprintDropDown` since you're able to check the value `component.sprintsList` that is updated by this method.

Try to rewrite your test as follows:

```
it('dropdown upon button click should update sprintsList', () => {

    // given
    const sortedList = [{
                          id: "3712",
                          name: "DCT 3.128.1 Sp1 (11Dec-24Dec)",
                          status: "ACTIVE",
                          sprintLink: null,
                          startDate: "2019-12-11"
                       }];
    spyOn(component.teamboardService, 'sortSprintsBasedOnEndDate').and.returnValue(sortedList);

    // when
    component.setResponseForButton(); 

    // then
    const expected = [{item_id: "3712", item_text: "DCT 3.128.1 Sp1 (11Dec-24Dec)"}];
    expect(component.sprintsList).toEqual(expected );
});
```

Comment: No I first call component.setResponseForButton and then that member furher calls populateSprintDropDown method where I want to created sprintsList

Comment: I have updated the question. sortedList  does not exist on component level its basically a list that is returned by a service.

Comment: Now that you edited method `setResponseForButton`, it makes it clear from where `sortedList` comes from. I'll update my answer accordingly. Does `teamboardService.sortSprintsBasedOnEndDate()` not take any argument? How does `Sprint` interface look like?